# Spark: cast bytearray to bigint

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

Trying to cast kafka key (binary/bytearray) to long/bigint using pyspark and spark sql results in data type mismatch: cannot cast binary to bigint

Environment details:

```
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 30 2018, 01:22:34)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.0.cloudera2
      /_/

Using Python version 3.6.8 (default, Dec 30 2018 01:22:34)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
```

Test case:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, BinaryType
df1_schema = StructType([StructField("key", BinaryType())])
df1_value = [[bytearray([0, 6, 199, 95, 77, 184, 55, 169])]]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df1_value,schema=df1_schema)
df1.printSchema()
#root
# |-- key: binary (nullable = true)

df1.show(truncate=False)
#+-------------------------+
#|key                      |
#+-------------------------+
#|[00 06 C7 5F 4D B8 37 A9]|
#+-------------------------+

df1.selectExpr('cast(key as bigint)').show(truncate=False)
```

Error:

> ```
> (...)  File "/app/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.316101/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o63.selectExpr.
> : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'CAST(`key` AS BIGINT)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast binary to bigint; line 1 pos 0;
> (...)
> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve 'CAST(`key` AS BIGINT)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast binary to bigint; line 1 pos 0;\n'Project [unresolvedalias(cast(key#0 as bigint), None)]\n+- AnalysisBarrier\n      +- LogicalRDD [key#0], false\n"
> ```

But my expected result would be `1908062000002985`, e.g.:

```
dfpd = df1.toPandas()
int.from_bytes(dfpd['key'].values[0], byteorder='big')
#1908062000002985
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`pyspark.sql.functions.hex`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.hex) and [`pyspark.sql.functions.conv`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.conv):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, conv, hex

df1.withColumn("num", conv(hex(col("key")), 16, 10).cast("bigint")).show(truncate=False)
#+-------------------------+----------------+
#|key                      |num             |
#+-------------------------+----------------+
#|[00 06 C7 5F 4D B8 37 A9]|1908062000002985|
#+-------------------------+----------------+
```

The `cast("bigint")` is only required if you want the result to be a `long` because `conv` returns a `StringType()`.