# How to filter not simple binary data column in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark, filter, binary

Sample of my `df` is:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |                  binary_col                                                                                  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | [08 01 10 0D 00 0E CC 93 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 FF BF 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 3F BE 2B 00 00]|
| 2 | [08 01 10 0D 00 0E CC 93 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 FF BF 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 3F 57 66 00 00]|
| 3 | [08 01 10 0D 00 0E CC 93 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C0 FF BF 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 3F D5 69 00 00]|
| 4 | [08 01 10 0D 00 0E CC 93 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 FF BF 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 3F 5A 60 00 00]|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

with these schema `(df.printSchema())`

```
|-- id: int (nullable = true)
|-- binary_col: binary (nullable = true)
```

And I want to filter only the values with `[08 01 10 0D 00 0E CC 93 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 FF BF 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 3F BE 2B 00 00]` (It doesn't work filtering `id=1` because there are other `ids` in the df)

I've tried to cast binary to `bigint` to filter later like here: [Spark: cast bytearray to bigint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57374236/spark-cast-bytearray-to-bigint)
by doing `df.withColumn('casted_bin', F.conv(F.hex(F.col("binary_col")), 16, 10).cast("bigint")).show(truncate=False)` but it didn't work.

**How can I filter any kind of binary data type?**

**Note**: I had asked previously here ([How to filter Pyspark column with binary data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73408330/how-to-filter-pyspark-column-with-binary-data-type)) but it was a very simple binary data and the answer generated the binary from a numeric value while now I don't know how to generate the numeric value.

Comment: are you not able to use `unhex()` here? `func.unhex(func.lit('0801100D000ECC9301000000010000000000000080FFBF40000000000000F03FBE2B0000'))`

Comment: It worked, thank you! I was not trimming the white spaces that's why it was retuning nothing.